# frame pointer register 'ebx' modified by inline assembly code in xatomic.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, assembly, atomic

Okay I stopped to most obscure bug what I have ever encountered. I would have commented on the almost exactly same question but I do not have enough reputation.. :(
What the bug does is that my program tries to execute on memory area that is not executable when the program tries to return from function. "Access violation on *executing* address 0x00000000".
I tracked the bug taking place in Visual Studio 2012's xatomic.h header (#include 'atomic' C++11 standard header) where it overwrites ebx register in x86 inline assembly. Once that happens the thread's stack is destroyed permanently.

I know quite precisely when this happens. The bug is triggered by boost::lockfree::queue::empty() function and only in release build with optimizations on. The empty() function must be inlined by compiler into it's caller function. The program works perfectly fine on debug mode as the empty() function is not inlined.

I get many compiler warnings about modifying the ebx register:

```
"include\boost-1_55\boost\atomic\detail\windows.hpp(1598): warning C4731: 'BuzyStack<JobPool>::push' : frame pointer register 'ebx' modified by inline assembly code"
"include\boost-1_55\boost\atomic\detail\windows.hpp(1598): warning C4731: 'BuzyStack<JobPool>::push' : frame pointer register 'ebx' modified by inline assembly code"
"y:\work\visualstudio\vc\include\xatomic.h(2133): warning C4731: 'ThreadSubSystem::join_pool' : frame pointer register 'ebx' modified by inline assembly code"
"y:\work\visualstudio\vc\include\xatomic.h(2137): warning C4731: 'ThreadSubSystem::join_pool' : frame pointer register 'ebx' modified by inline assembly code"
```

BuzyStack is my concurrent 'thread pool stack' that manages threading pools. Items can be concurrently pushed to/poped from the BuzyStack.

I realy do need the boost::lockfree::queue::empty() function, so how do I fix this?

What I have already done is quite radical action. I modified the Visual Studio 2012 (Update 4) xatomic.h header __asm {} parts, where the ebx register is overwritten. I force preserving the ebx register by saving it at begining of __asm block into temporal var and restoring the ebx at end of __asm block. This works. The bug is gone, but I can still see point in my program where the call stack is temporaly invalid. Also the number of compiler warnings doubled when I did this change.

**(Update)**
Sorry for being unclear with the question: Shortly: How do I fix this bug? I seems to be the MSVC compiler's fault.

I do not have any inline asm code in my code what so ever. All warnings are generated by code in boost-1.55 atomic and lockfree libraries plus MSVC 2012 xatomic.h header.
The standard header mod was only a temporal workaround and I do not use the modded header any more nor the empty() function. The bug still exists and destroys my stack today if I try call the empty() function.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking, are you asking how you can fix your compiler to not exhibit this bug?

Comment: The bug should be elsewhere, you don't have to update the standard library headers.

Comment: Yes, I'm kinda asking how to fix my compiler.

Comment: @Geoffroy I got this bug as well. The only way for me to avoid it was to remove all uses of `std::atomic<T>` where `sizeof(T)==8`. Before the complete application crashed, now everything works as sweet as pie! I guess changing to a newer compiler version might also remove the bug.